# textFieldShouldReturnで生成したつもりのボタンが表示されない

Tags: swift, xcode

簡単なTodoリストを作ろうとしています。現時点は、チェックボックスを作り終えた段階です。
evernoteのように、改行したら新しいチェックボックスが出現するようにしたのですが、苦戦しています。textFieldShouldReturnを使おうとしているのですが、ここで生成しているつもりのボタンが画面に表示されません。（resignFristResponder()の改行は反映されています。）どこが悪いのか、ご指摘頂けたら幸いです。
※以下では、子クラスとしてチェックボックスを生成する「CheckBox」というクラスを持っています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: CheckBox) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var WhatToDo: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        WhatToDo.delegate = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ WhatToDo: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let newBox : UIButton = CheckBox()
        newBox.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y:100)
        newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(newBox)
        WhatToDo.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

class CheckBox: UIButton {
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked-box")
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked-box")

    var isChecked : Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for:.normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for:.normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttondClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttondClicked(_ sender:UIButton){
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
            }else{
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CheckBox`を表示しようとしているのに、肝心のそのコードが示されていません。あなたが直面している事象を再現するのに必要十分なコードをご提示ください。また、その`CheckBox`そのものは確実に正しく実装されているのでしょうか。(新しいViewを動的にsubviewに加える際に`layer.position`だけを指定するというのは滅多に見られない実装です。)例えば`viewDidLoad()`の中なら、その`CheckBox`は正しく表示できるのでしょうか。

Comment: @OOPer 失礼いたしました。編集して追加しておきます。

Comment: コードの追記ありがとうございました。いくつかの要因が複合しているようです。動作確認をしながら回答をまとめておりますので、今しばらくお待ちください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

根本的には、 **`CheckBox`の実装が`init()`でインスタンス化できるように作られていない** というのが原因ですね。`awakeFromNib()`というのはNibファイル(xibかstoryboard)からインスタンス化した時にしか呼ばれないので、`init()`でインスタンス化した場合には、正しく初期化されません。

例えば、`CheckBox`クラスに次のようなコードを書き加えてみてください。

```
init() {
    let frm = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: checkedImage.size)
    super.init(frame: frm)
    awakeFromNib()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

上記の修正だけでもチェックボックスが表示されるようになるはずですが、コメントに書いたように`layer.position`で位置合わせをするのは標準的とは言えないので、`addSubview`する部分は例えば次のように書き換えるべきでしょう。

```
    let newBox : UIButton = CheckBox()
    newBox.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y:100), size: newBox.frame.size) //<- 表示位置は`frame`で指定する
    newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(newBox)
```

---

上記に非掲載の部分でコードの読みにくい部分を書き換えながら試したので、若干修正が必要かもしれません。何かお気付きの点があればコメント等でお知らせください。

コメントで指摘していただきましたが、上記のコードは、プロパティの宣言を

```
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked-box")!
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked-box")!
```

のように修正したのを前提で書いてありましたが、その点を記載し忘れていました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。(`UIImage.init(named:)`が`nil`を返すのは、アプリの構成ミスで`"checked-box"`とかで指定された画像リソースが存在しない場合だけなので、意図的にさっさと強制アンラップの`!`を使用しています。)

Comment: 細かいところですが、初期化のところで    size: checkedImage.size  をsize: (checkedImage?.size)!  としなければならなかったこと以外は自分がやりたかったように動作しました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。ご指摘の場所については、`checkedImage`の宣言を`let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked-box")!`に変えたのをすっかり忘れておりました。ちなみに最終的に強制アンラップの`!`が必要ならできるだけ早くアンラップした方が、コードの見通しがよくなります。(`(checkedImage?.size)!`よりは`checkedImage!.size`の方が良いでしょう。)

Comment: なるほど、勉強になります。まだまだ駆け出しですが頑張っていこうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

```
newBox.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y:100)
```

この行を次に書き換えてください。

```
newBox.frame = CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 80.0, height: 60.0)
```

チェックボックスが表示されると思います。
`UIButton`のサブクラス`CheckBox`のイニシアライザがどうなってるかなんですけど、そこで、表示のサイズ（`CGSize`）の設定が含まれていないと、`UIButton`（のスーパークラスの`UIView`）のデフォルト`CGRect.zero`、すなわち面積0になるので、表示されても見えない状態となります。

Comment: 確かに表示されました。しかし、余計だろうと思って今backgroundColorのところを省いて実行したところ、何も表示されなくなってしまったのですが、この場合色を指定しなくてもCheckBoxの情報が引き継がれる、ということはないのでしょうか。ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ありません。

Comment: 根本的解決は、`UIButton`のサブクラス`CheckBox`を、しっかり作り込むことです。なお、メソッド`awakeFromNib()`は、Nib（Xib）ファイル、Storyboardファイルからインスタンスを生成する時限定で呼ばれるメソッドなので、プログラムでインスタンスを生成する場合には、呼ばれません。すなわち、今回のケースでは、ボタンのImageがセットされないという結果になります。